# ng-click not working inside the ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

*I'am trying to display the products based on the brands but ng-click inside ng-repeat not working.
But ng-click outside the ng-repeat working fine.**Is there any conflict inside ng-repeat...?***

**Module**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myapplication', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource','uiSlider']);
```

**My View**

```
<a style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="Brandfilters = ''">All Brands</a>

<div class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="product in products | unique: 'brand'" >
   <a style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="Brandfilters='{{product.brand}}'">{{product.brand}}</a>
</div>
```

**My Controller**

```
myApp.controller("StoreListCtr", ['$scope', '$http', '$resource',  '$location', 
      function($scope, $http, $resource, $location) {

        $scope.products = Products.query();
        $scope.Brandfilters = null;
        $scope.lower_price = 100;
        $scope.upper_price = 500;

        $scope.priceRange = function(products) {
          return (products['cost'] >= $scope.lower_price 
                          && products['cost'] <=$scope.upper_price);
        };
}])
```

Comment: it should act as filter in products display on index page...

Comment: If my solution don't work, try to reproduce your bug in a plunker. It will be easier to help you that way.

Comment: Can you try to replace your ng-click inside your ng-repeat by this : alert(product.brand) and tell us how it behave ?

Comment: Remove the curly brackets and single quotes: `ng-click="Brandfilters=product.brand"`

Comment: What does your `module` look like?

Comment: var myApp = angular.module('myapplication', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource','uiSlider']);

Answer (score 0):

Just try

```
<div class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="product in products | unique: 'brand'" >
   <a style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="Brandfilters ='product.brand'">{{product.brand}}</a>
</div>
```

Comment: no it's not working.it displayed something like "<a class="ng-binding" ng-click="Brandfilters = 'product.brand'" style="cursor:pointer">Microsoft</a>"

Comment: What error are you getting in console ? Please check and share your error

Comment: Will you please create a jsfiddle ? So I can dig more on it.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your ng-repeat is evaluated code so you don't have to use {{}}.

```
<div class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="product in products | unique: 'brand'" >
   <a style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="Brandfilters = product.brand">{{product.brand}}</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Working example - http://plnkr.co/edit/DnTE05Vpo6erMgfpQQjo?p=preview

Try this -

Replace -

```
<a style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="Brandfilters='{{product.brand}}'">{{product.brand}}</a>
```

With

```
 <a style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="setBrand(product.brand)">{{product.brand}}</a>
```

And in controller

```
$scope.setBrand = function(brandName) {
      $scope.Brandfilters = brandName;
}
```

Comment: Its working for me. Please check this - http://plnkr.co/edit/DnTE05Vpo6erMgfpQQjo?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You may need to inject the correct directive, maybe `'ui.directives'` into the module, or it might be `ui.utils` ?

```
var myApp = angular.module('myapplication', 
                               ['ngRoute', 'ngResource','uiSlider', 'ui.directives']);
```

On looking at the documentation, you may need `ui.utils`...

```
var myApp = angular.module('myapplication', 
                               ['ngRoute', 'ngResource','uiSlider', 'ui.utils']);
```

See [GitHub](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils) resource.